# Output for javascript program is 'undefined' when trying to run in command line

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working through some Javascript coding problems and I want to print the output of the array on my command line using `node file.js` but I keep getting `undefined` as the output. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I've tried adding a `console.log` statement in different areas of the code. Here is the code:

```
    var sortArrayByParity = function(A) {
    E = [];
    O = [];
    for (i = 0; i < A; i++){
        if (A[i] % 2 === 0){
            E.push(A[i]);
        }
         else {
            O.push(A[i]);
        }
    }
    return E.concat(O);
    console.log(E);
};
```

Comment: any code after `return` will not execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code:

The `console.log()` after your `return` will not run, as any code after a `return` will not be executed as the function is no longer running.

Another issue is your `for` loop. Currently, you are not looping as your condition `i < A` isn't correct. Instead, you want to loop over the `length` of `A` using:

```
for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  // Do code
}
```

See example below:

```js
var sortArrayByParity = function(A) {
  E = [];
  O = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i] % 2 === 0) {
      E.push(A[i]);
    } else {
      O.push(A[i]);
    }
  }
  
  return E.concat(O);
};

var res = sortArrayByParity([1, 2, 3, 4]);  
console.log(res); // [2, 4, 1, 3] (sorted by evens first, odds second)
```

Comment: @user9476376 no worries! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

well there is some validation you should do.

- Make sure to pass an array
- You missing to add the A.length in the for loop

  ```
  var sortArrayByParity = function(A) {
      let E = [];
      let O = [];
      let errMsg = ''
      // Make sure you're passing and array
      if ( ! A instanceof Array ) {
        return errMsg = ' Argument is not an array '
       }
        for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
            if (A[i] % 2 === 0){
                E.push(A[i]);
            }
             else {
                O.push(A[i]);
            }
      }
      console.log(E);
      return E.concat(O);
  };
  ```

this should work ;)